# Scala annotation macro only works with pre-defined classes

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macros, scala-macro-paradise

**Note: There's an EDIT below!**
**Note: There's another EDIT below!**

I have written a Scala annotation macro that is being passed a class and creates (or rather populates) a case object. The name of the case object is the same as the name of the passed class. More importantly, for every field of the passed class, there will be a field in the case object of the same name. The fields of the case object, however, are all of type `String`, and their value is the name of the type of the respective field in the passed class. Example:

```
// Using the annotation macro to populate a case object called `String`
@RegisterClass(classOf[String]) case object String

// The class `String` defines a field called `value` of type `char[]`.
// The case object also has a field `value`, containing `"char[]"`.
println(String.value) // Prints `"char[]"` to the console
```

This, however, seems to only work with pre-defined classes such as `String`. If I define a `case class A(...)` and try to do `@RegisterClass(classOf[A]) case object A`, I get the following error:

```
[info]   scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed:
[info]   
[info]   not found: type A
```

What have I done wrong? The code of my macro can be found below. Also, if someone notices un-idiomatic Scala or bad practices in general, I wouldn't mind a hint. Thank you very much in advance!

```
class RegisterClass[T](clazz: Class[T]) extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*) =
    macro RegisterClass.expandImpl[T]
}

object RegisterClass {
  def expandImpl[T](c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*) = {
    import c.universe._
    val clazz: Class[T] = c.prefix.tree match {
      case q"new RegisterClass($clazz)" => c.eval[Class[T]](c.Expr(clazz))
      case _ =>  c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "RegisterClass: Annotation expects a Class[T] instance as argument.")
    }
    annottees.map(_.tree) match {
      case List(q"case object $caseObjectName") =>
        if (caseObjectName.toString != clazz.getSimpleName)
          c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "RegisterClass: Annotated case object and class T of passed Class[T] instance" +
            "must have the same name.")
        val clazzFields = clazz.getDeclaredFields.map(field => field.getName -> field.getType.getSimpleName).toList
        val caseObjectFields = clazzFields.map(field => {
          val fieldName: TermName = field._1
          val fieldType: String = field._2
          q"val $fieldName = $fieldType"
        })
        c.Expr[Any](q"case object $caseObjectName { ..$caseObjectFields }")
      case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "RegisterClass: Annotation must be applied to a case object definition.")
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT: As Eugene Burmako pointed out, the error happens because `class A` hasn't been compiled yet, so a `java.lang.Class` for it doesn't exist. I have now started a bounty of 100 StackOverflow points for everyone who as an idea how one could get this to work!**

**EDIT 2: Some background on the use case: As part of my bachelor thesis I am working on a Scala DSL for expressing queries for event processing systems. Those queries are traditionally expressed as strings, which induces a lot of problems. A typical query would look like that: "select A.id, B.timestamp from pattern[A -> B]". Meaning: If an event of type `A` occurs and after that an event of type `B` occurs, too, give me the `id` of the `A` event and the `timestamp` of the `B` event. The types `A` and `B` usually are simple Java classes over which I have no control. `id` and `timestamp` are fields of those classes. I would like queries of my DSL to look like that: `select (A.id, B.timestamp) { /* ... * / }`. This means that for every class representing an event type, e.g., `A`, I need a companion object -- ideally of the same name. This companion object should have the same fields as the respective class, so that I can pass its fields to the `select` function, like so: `select (A.id, B.timestamp) { /* ... * / }`. This way, if I tried to pass `A.idd` to the `select` function, it would fail at compile-time if there was no such field in the original class -- because then there would not be one in the companion object either.**

Comment: I don't know if this actually works, but perhaps it helps: What if you add a field to the case object. I.e., `@RegisterClass case object String { type T = String }` or `@RegisterClass case object String { val t : String = _ }`. Then possibly the annotation macro can get access to the type `T` or the type of `t` by inspecting the annottee? (I don't know if this works, that's why I don't post an answer, but perhaps the idea helps somehow.)

Comment: Couple thoughts: (1) Rewriting objects on such a large scale is a Bad Idea since you are essentially hiding/overwriting existing functionality. (2) Spark 2.0 does something similar (but not type-checked, which would be nice) with [columns](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column) inside operations like `select`, `join`, `groupby` (see the examples [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset)). (3) Why not make a compiler plugin for this? Then you can "rewrite" Scala syntax locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an answer to your macro problem, but it could be a solution to your general problem.
If you can allow a minor change to the syntax of your DSL this might be possible without using macro's (depending on other requirements not mentioned in this question).

```
scala> class Select[A,B]{
     |   def apply[R,S](fa: A => R, fb: B => S)(body: => Unit) = ???
     | }
defined class Select

scala> def select[A,B] = new Select[A,B]
select: [A, B]=> Select[A,B]

scala> class MyA { def id = 42L }
defined class MyA

scala> class MyB { def timestamp = "foo" }
defined class MyB

scala> select[A,B](_.id, _.timestamp){ /* ... */ }
scala.NotImplementedError: an implementation is missing
```

I use the class `Select` here as a means to be able to specify the types of your event classes while letting the compiler infer the result types of the functions `fa` and `fb`. If your don't need those result types you could just write it as `def select[A,B](fa: A => Any, fb: B => Any)(body: => Unit) = ???`.

If necessary you can still implement the `select` or `apply` method as a macro. But using this syntax, you will no longer need to generate objects with macro annotations.

Comment: This approach is awesome! I have just one more question: What would be a Scala-esque way to realize this with an arbitrary amount of parameters for the `select` function? So one could also do this: `select[A, B, C](_.foo, _.bar, _.baz)`

Comment: @scalarookie for this you could actually use a `macro`. Funny.